# Sockets - Communication between C# and JAVA Android

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets

I have a JAVA application that is reading a message:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    new Thread((new ClientThread())).start();
    //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
   // startActivity(i);
}

//Thread que inicia o socket
class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            InetAddress serveradress = InetAddress.getByName(server_IP);
            Log.e("TCP","A conetar...");
            socket = new Socket(serveradress,PORT);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while((mensagem = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                mensagem_final += mensagem;
            }
            txt.setText(mensagem_final);

            if(in.readLine() == null)
            {
                Log.e("TCP","Nao tem mensagens");
            }
            Log.e("MSG",mensagem);

            socket.close();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to create a server in C# and all extra code is freezing when I run the server. And I still cant get the message from C# server.

```
            Servidor servidor = new Servidor();
            servidor.server();



 class Servidor
{
    public void server()
    {

            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            TcpListener tcplistener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6000);
            tcplistener.Start();


            TcpClient tcpclient = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient();

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            NetworkStream ns = tcpclient.GetStream();

            string welcome = "Ola";
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
            ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);



    }
}
```

Any help? I use Servidor servidor = new Servidor();
            servidor.server(); in another windowsform. This window forms load another windowsforms and should also load the server. But everything on the windowsforms just freezes. Maybe I need threads?

Comment: `I have a JAVA application`. To me it looks like Androd code.

Comment: It's an android app written in java.

Comment: `txt.setText(mensagem_final);`. What is type of `txt` ? If it is a TextView then remove that statement as you cannot update the gui inside a thread.

Comment: Yes it is a Textview. Where do I put it then? Do I need a timer to update the textviews?

Comment: Then change the subject and your intro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AcceptTcpClient is a blocking call, and it really needs to be handled by something that spawns a new thread each time it succeeds, but for a single instance just try wrapping in a new thread e.g.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    TcpListener tcplistener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6000);
    tcplistener.Start();


    TcpClient tcpclient = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient();

    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    NetworkStream ns = tcpclient.GetStream();

    string welcome = "Ola";
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
    ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);



});
```

Comment: What is Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ?? I dont have anything like this in c#

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519(v=vs.110).aspx